# Symfony 2 get defined roles in a custom form field type

Tags: forms, symfony, roles

In my project I want the admins to be able to change the required role to see certain content using a choice field.
I have an ArticleType that builds the form for me:

```
class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{   
    ...

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('title')
                ->add('requiredRole', 'choice');

    }

    ...
}
```

I also want to to translate the roles. For example 'ROLE_ADMIN' is translated as 'Admins'.
Since I need this function in some different forms too, I thought creating a custom form field type would be a good solution.

But then I have the problem that I can't access the defined roles.

I got it to work without a custom field type with this in the controller

```
$form = $this->createForm(new ArticleType($this->container->getParameter('security.role_hierarchy.roles')), $article);
```

and this in the ArticleType

```
class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{   
    ...

    private $roles;

    public function __contruct($roles)
    {
        $this->roles = $this->refactorRoles($roles);
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('title')
                ->add('requiredRole', 'choice', array('choices' => $this->roles);

    }

    ...
}
```

But with this solution I have to include the `refactorRoles` function in every Type i need the roles field in and when I add or rename a role I have to change every Type again.

So my question is, how can I create a custom roleType can access the defined roles and translate them?
Also, is this a good idea or should I do something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you don't necessarily need to do this. The better practice would probably be to create a Role entity add your corresponding roles' front-end name (Admin) and back-end value (ROLE_ADMIN) and create a One-To-Many association to the Article entity. You can then use the entity field (= choice field of entities) directly in the builder of your form's type file and you can specify which property should be shown (you'd want the front-end name). 
To show an article you will need to query join those tables and from there check the user's role to the article minimum role's back-end value.

One of the advantages of the Doctrine ORM is to make those kind of things trivial once you get used to it.

Comment: This might be stupid, but I don't quite get your solution. You would create an Entity that contains the front end name and the back end value of each role and generate a table from that? Or would you use an entity that has no table, but generates an array with the names and values in the `__construct()` function?
Edit: Entities must have a table, so I guess it's the first one right?